# Haskell function that substitutes a DNA base

Tags: haskell, bioinformatics

I am trying to create a function in Haskell that substitutes a DNA base with another base. This is what my function is. When I run the test, I get `False` rather than `True`. I am not sure what I could be doing wrong with this function.

```
bases = "AGCT"
substitutions :: String -> [String]
substitutions "" = []
substitutions (c:cs) = ((map (:cs)) bases) ++ (map (c:) (substitutions cs))

p12tests = [substitutions "ACT" == ["ACT","AAT","ACA","GCT","AGT","ACG","CCT","ACT","ACC","TCT","ATT","ACT"]]
```

Comment: What is the value of `bases`? If I set it to `bases = "AGCT"`, the result is `[True]`. I suspect the order of the results is just different.

Comment: valuse of bases is, bases = "AGCT"

Comment: That is why I am confused. On my system when ran it says false.

Comment: It *will* be false if your value of `bases` is different. `"ACTG"` and `"AGTC"`, for example, are two different strings and produce two differently ordered results, even if you consider the resulting lists to be the same sets.

Comment: I had the wrong test that I was using. I updated the question to the correct test that needs to be used. Does this change anything? I am new to haskell.

Comment: You try replacing the first base in the sequence (the `A` in `ACT`) with each of the choices from the universe (`AGCT`), then recurse on the rest of the sequence (the `CT` in `ACT`). The person who wrote the test tried replacing each base in the sequence (`ACT`) with the first choice from the universe (the `A` in `AGCT`), then recursed on the rest of the universe (the `GCT` in `AGCT`). It's not immediately obvious to me that either strategy is obviously "better".

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you don't care about the order of substitutions returned by your function, I would recommend modifying your test to compare the **sorted** lists:

```
import Data.List   -- to import "sort" function

-- revised test
p12tests = sort (substitutions "ACT") == 
  sort ["ACT","AAT","ACA","GCT","AGT","ACG","CCT","ACT","ACC","TCT","ATT","ACT"]
```

This modified test returns `True` for me.